# AWS SAM build failing NpmExecutionError code 255

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

After long hours searching for answers, I give up and ask for help, hopefully someone will also benefit from this.

Here is the problem, I have a project which uses AWS SAM. When i run `sam build` it fails with `NpmExecutionError` and a status code `255`. Here is where i first searched for

[Stackoverflow sam build fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622227/sam-build-fails-with-build-failed-error-nodejsnpmbuildernpmpack-npm-failed)
[github sam build fail](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1906)
[github (2) sam build fail](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4183)

I tried with `sam build --debug` and `sam build -u --debug`, the latter gave me the error that esbuild is missing, but the former didn't gave me any error aside `NPM Failed:`

I tried to install esbuild globally with npm, then with brew, then on the project in `dependencies` as well as `devDependencies`.

I tried to update everything I installed with brew.

I tried to uninstall and re-install aws cli and sam cli.

I tried to rm node_modules and install again

I tried to update npm

Here are some information about my setup
`npm => 9.1.1`
`node => v16.17.0`
`aws cli => aws-cli/2.8.12 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/22.1.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`
`sam => SAM CLI, version 1.63.0`
`esbuild => 0.15.14`

Here are the screenshot of the error log
`sam build -u --debug`
[image]

`sam build --debug`
[image]
[image]

PS: what is hidden are information about telemetry data such as session_id, request_id, etc...

A collegue of mine successfully build the exact same project with the exact same configuration which confuses me.

Also I have two folder, one that contains a template.yml with `AWS::Serverless::Api` (the one who fails, see screenshot) but I also have another folder with a template.yml with `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion` which successfully build

Thanks to everyone who are willing to help me

EDIT: I tried using Hello world project from AWS SAM (typescript, zip) and the build even fail for this project

EDIT 2: I tried to comment the Metadata part containing esbuild config and the build success so I don't know why it fails with esbuild

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    # Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
    #   BuildMethod: esbuild
    #   BuildProperties:
    #     Minify: true
    #     Target: "es2020"
    #     # Sourcemap: true # Enabling source maps will create the required NODE_OPTIONS environment variables on your lambda function during sam build
    #     EntryPoints: 
    #     - app.ts
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I removed Node from brew as I use the `n` package, then I installed the latest version of Node using `n v18.12.1` and by doing this it updated my npm version to `8.19.2` which seemed to have solved the problem

I also removed esbuild both from npm and brew package, then I reinstalled it thought `npm -g install esbuild`